# NIFI HDF Node Crashing

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-dataflow

We have a three node Nifi HDF cluster installed which was running fine. We changed the path to NiFi content repository default dir and then restarted NiFi.
After restart all three nodes were running fine, but as soon as we started the flow for testing, node 2 Stopped and when I tried to start, It restarted and after a while it disconnects from the cluster on its own.

I am attaching the logs for reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz5zb.png)
We are using HDF Version 3.0.0 and NiFi Version 1.2.0.3.0.2.0-76.

Any suggestions??

Comment: In order to help you, we need to first understand what is happening. Can you edit your question and post the logs so they can be looked at?

Comment: Hi @Thomas, Hope the edit and the pictures of logs help you.